# Cant enable fail2ban jail sshd

Tags: python, centos6, systemd, fail2ban

When enabled sshd jail i see `Starting fail2ban: ERROR  NOK: ("Failed to initialize any backend for Jail 'sshd'",)
ERROR  NOK: ('sshd',)`
In logs :
`ERROR Backend 'systemd' failed to initialize due to No module named systemd`
`ERROR Failed to initialize any backend for Jail 'sshd'`

Centos 6.7 no have systemd module .
CentOS 6.7, python 2.6

Answer (score 6):

Just replace in you jail config **backend** to **auto**
From

```
[sshd]
enabled = true
filter = sshd
port    = ssh
logpath = %(sshd_log)s
backend = %(sshd_backend)s
```

To

```
[sshd]
enabled = true
filter = sshd
port    = ssh
logpath = %(sshd_log)s
backend = auto
```

And restart service `service fail2ban restart`

Comment: I'm guessing it was broken in/by fail2ban-0.9.6-1.el6.noarch.
Fix above works for me - thanks

Comment: @TheGingerDog is right; and also from 0.9.6-1, you'll need to configure the path to `mysqld.log`

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error is that after installation of `fail2ban` the configuration file `/etc/fail2ban/paths-fedora.conf` contains several lines, which set backends for some applications to `systemd`, which is not present in CentOS 6.x.

Just remove all strings like

```
syslog_backend = systemd
sshd_backend = systemd
dropbear_backend = systemd
proftpd_backend = systemd
pureftpd_backend = systemd
wuftpd_backend = systemd
postfix_backend = systemd
dovecot_backend = systemd
```

from `/etc/fail2ban/paths-fedora.conf` (or search for the file, which contains such strings, using grep). In this case you do not need to change `backend = %(sshd_backend)s` to `backend = auto` -- everything will work fine without such changes.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by editing the `paths-common.conf` file from:

`default_backend = %(default/backend)s`

to:

`default_backend = pynotify` or `default_backend = auto`